# Latin Cross symbol in HTML showing as emoji on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html-entities, html-encode

I am using the Latin Cross symbol on a html page. On desktop it is showing like "✝" but on the iPhone it is showing as emoji.

here is sample code

```
<p>I will display &#10013;</p>
```

here is the screenshot of iphone
[Dagger icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlMDv.png)

Is there any way to show Latin Cross symbol as "✝" on all devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

`<p>I will display &#10013;&#xFE0E;</p>`

U+FE0E is a ‘variation selector’ that indicates that text-rendering (rather than emoji) is preferred.